# Xcode 8 - Some buttons border removed

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uibutton, xcode8

I just updated my Xcode ver from 7.3 to 8.0 and some buttons borders disappeared.

The code looks fine, so I really don't know what happened to the layers.
btw - in some other controllers I can see the layers borders.

```
self.button.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
self.button.layer.borderWidth = 2;
self.button.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetHeight(self.button.frame) / 2;
```

before: (The image is only for example - the borders looks different at real time)

[image: before:]

now:

[image: now:]

Comment: try this line in last : self.button.clipsToBounds = YES

Comment: Surprisingly, even your before button corner radius does not seems half of your button height.

Comment: The image is only for example...

Comment: @Asi Givati Please check my answer and reply

Comment: Ok will check soon, thanks

Comment: I checked it and the problem not related to the QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h, but i gave you +1 anyway ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason is that XCode 8 introduces a new way to zoom in Storyboards.

Before XCode 8, in the view controller life cycle, `frames` were not known in viewDidLoad (or in properties `didSet`). You had to wait until viewDidLayoutSubviews (which is when Autolayout had finished applying the constraints to determine the frames of every subview in the main view.
But `bounds` were accessible before that: they were just set to the size of the IBOutlet in the storyboard.

In XCode 8, things are different : due to their new zooming system, even the `bounds`are not correct before ViewDidLayoutSubviews (they may exist but with dummy values like 1000 x 1000).

In conclusion :

- you can use such things as cornerRadius in viewDidLoad or in the IBOutlet
  didSet, as long as you use a **fixed value**
- if you need to define your cornerRadius based on `bounds`, then **do so in viewDidLayoutSubviews**, or use **NSLayoutConstraints** (their value is fixed and known from Autolayout)
- if you need to use cornerRadius in **views** (like UITableViewCell or UICollectionViewCell subclasses), then you can either do so in `layoutSubviews` (but then you need to give either a fixed value or a NSLayoutConstraint constant to cornerRadius), or in `awakeFromNib`(in that case, just add `self.layoutIfNeeded` before doing anything frame- or boounds-related, in order to force the cell to recalculate its subviews' frame).

Comment: 1000 x 1000 - its exactly the dummy frame I saw which cause the problem. Now after your great answer - I'll know better how to handle it next time :)

Comment: So frustrating to waste so much time debugging this! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: What is the analogous function to viewDidLayoutSubviews for loading custom views built in Storyboard? `awakeFromNib` and `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` also show the dummy 1000x1000 frame sizes in Xcode 8 though this worked in Xcode 7.

Comment: 'LayoutSubviews' occurs in the custom view between the view controller's 'ViewWillLayoutSubviews' and 'ViewDidLayoutSubviews'

Comment: @Crashalot did you manage to fix this issue. I have same problem like you. 
how you fix it?

Answer (score 4):

I think problem in it:

```
CGRectGetHeight(self.button.frame) / 2;
```

When you set corner i think height button don't have value or value to larger border will don't show. You can try change it to

```
self.button.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
```

If work, I think you can check your logic and set it when height button get right value.

Comment: But it worked until yesterday when i worked with Xcode 7 :)

Comment: I see. But now you using xcode8 and with ios 10 so Something changed.

Comment: So that was the problem. in Xcode 7 CGRectGetHeight(self.button.frame) / 2 worked just fine but now for some reason i have to add height constraint to this button and split it in 2 to get the correct height for the corner radius.

Comment: @AsiGivati yup had same issue where frames values no longer worked in Xcode 8 but did work in Xcode 7. Argh!

Comment: @Crashalot - this is an easy fix - just move your code from 'viewDidLoad' to 'viewDidLayoutSubviews'

Answer (score 2):

Try this and check:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

self.button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
self.button.layer.borderWidth = 2;
self.button.layer.cornerRadius = 5; // Change this value on your requirement
self.button.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

To force view frame to be calculated, you can try with layoutIfNeeded.
For example for a label in a UITableViewCell :

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.qualityIndexLabel.makeRound()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use dispatch_after

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.8 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
self.button.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
self.button.layer.borderWidth = 2;
self.button.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetHeight(self.button.frame) / 2;    });
```

Answer (score -1):

the RoundedRect is deprecated use UIButtonTypeSystem instead. 
see https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton?language=objc for more information.