# Corner radius for UIButton not working after upgrading to Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I am setting the corner radius of `UIButton` as follows:

```
self.btnFBLogin.layer.cornerRadius = self.btnFBLogin.frame.size.height/2;
self.btnFBLogin.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

However, after upgrading to Xcode 8 it is not working. Button is not displayed in screen. However, if I do not set the corner radius it displays as a square box. Has anybody faced similar issue?

Comment: In XCode 8, due to their new zooming system,  bounds and frame are not correct before ViewDidLayoutSubviews (they may exist but with dummy values like 1000 x 1000) - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39495236/3150830

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all probability you are running that code *too soon* (e.g. `viewDidLoad`). Do it in, say, `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly I did.

Comment: Reviving this post as I had the same issue. I solved this issue by calling `layoutIfNeeded:` before setting the corner radius. What's the disadvantage of this approach?

Answer (score 13):

Try This

[image]

Make `Clip Subviews` checked

Hope this helps